# Can't find pvlib.pvsystem.Array

Tags: pvlib

I am using pvlib-python to model a series of photovoltaic installations.

I have been running the normal pvlib-python procedural code just fine (as described in the [intro tutorial](https://pvlib-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introtutorial.html).

I am now trying to extend my model to be able to cope with several arrays of panels in different directions etc, but connected to the same inverter. For this I though the easiest way would be to use pvlib.pvsystem.Array to create a list of Array-objects that I can then pass to the pvlib.pvsytem.PVSystem class (as described [here](https://pvlib-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pvsystem.html#pvsystem-and-arrays)).

My issue now is that I can't find pvsystem.Array at all? eg I'm just getting:

*AttributeError: module 'pvlib.pvsystem' has no attribute 'Array'*

when I try to create an instance of Array using:

```
from pvlib import pvsystem

module_parameters = {'pdc0': 5000, 'gamma_pdc': -0.004}

array_one = pvsystem.Array(module_parameters=module_parameters)

array_two = pvsystem.Array(module_parameters=module_parameters)

system_two_arrays = pvsystem.PVSystem(arrays=[array_one, array_two],
                                  inverter_parameters=inverter_parameters)
```

as described in the examples [in the PVSystem and Arrays page](https://pvlib-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pvsystem.html).

I am using pvlib-python=0.8.1, installed in my conda env using *conda install -c conda-forge pvlib-python*.

I am quite confused about this since I can obviously see all the documentation on pvsystem.Array on read-the-docs and see the source code on [pvlib's github](https://github.com/pvlib/pvlib-python/blob/master/pvlib/pvsystem.py#L1243-L1685).

When I look at the code in my conda env it doesn't have Array under pvsystem (or if I list it using dir(pvlib.pvsystem)), so it is something wrong with the installation, but I simply can't figure out what. I've tried installing pvlib again and using [different installation](https://pvlib-python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html) but always the same issue.

Am I missing something really obvious here?

Kind regards and thank you,

Answer (score 4):

This feature is not present in the current stable version (8.1).  If you want to use it already you could download the latest source as a zip file and install it, or clone the pvlib git repository on your computer.

Comment: Ok makes sense thank you, clone it from git and worked well!